# v-select validate not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: vue.js, v-select

Good day, how can i make v-select validate work on IE 11?
i added `require('es6-promise').polyfill();` on my vue script but till i encounter error Failed to generate render function.

```
<v-select :options="books" label="title" v-model="selected">
  <template #search="{attributes, events}">
    <input
      class="vs__search"
      :required="!selected"
      v-bind="attributes"
      v-on="events"
    />
  </template>
</v-select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solve by accessing the slot directly and binding the required attributes

```
<v-select :options="books" label="title" v-model="selected">
  <template #search="{attributes, events}">
    <input :required="!selected" aria-label="Search for option" role="combobox" type="search" autocomplete="off" class="vs__search">
  </template>
</v-select>
```